# Ошибка из Swal.fire Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Есть сайт посетителей бассейна.И там есть файл с Jquery кодом, которий вызывает модальное окно Swal.fire. И если я нажимаю подтвердить - отправляется Ajax запрос.

Файл подключаю через webpack.mix.js, сам сайтн написан на Ларавел. 
Все работает, но в консоле вылетает ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код файла, который я писал

```
$('body').on('click', '.add-visiting', async function () {
    const { value: desc } = await Swal.fire({
        title: 'Додаткові відомості?',
        input: 'textarea',
        cancelButtonText: 'Не додавати',
        inputPlaceholder: 'Додаткові відомості (не обов\'язково)',
        inputAttributes: {
            'aria-label': 'Додаткові відомості (не обов\'язково)'
        },
        showCancelButton: true,
        preConfirm: (desc) => {
            return $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/account/api/object/' + $(this).attr('data-object') + '/control-panel/abonements/add-visiting/' + $(this).attr('id'),
                headers: authHeaders,
                data: {
                    description: desc,
                }
            })
        },
    }).then((response) => {
        table.ajax.reload();
        if(response === true) {
            Swal.fire(`додано`)
        }
    })
});
```

А вот то, что находится в папке public...

```
$('body').on('click', '.add-visiting',
  /*#__PURE__*/
  _asyncToGenerator(
  /*#__PURE__*/
  _babel_runtime_regenerator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.mark(function _callee2() {
var _this3 = this;

var _ref4, desc;

return _babel_runtime_regenerator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.wrap(function _callee2$(_context2) {
  while (1) {
    switch (_context2.prev = _context2.next) {
      case 0:
        _context2.next = 2;
        return Swal.fire({
          title: 'Додаткові відомості?',
          input: 'textarea',
          cancelButtonText: 'Не додавати',
          inputPlaceholder: 'Додаткові відомості (не обов\'язково)',
          inputAttributes: {
            'aria-label': 'Додаткові відомості (не обов\'язково)'
          },
          showCancelButton: true,
          preConfirm: function preConfirm(desc) {
            return $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: '/account/api/object/' + $(_this3).attr('data-object') + '/control-panel/abonements/add-visiting/' + $(_this3).attr('id'),
              headers: authHeaders,
              data: {
                description: desc
              }
            });
          }
        }).then(function (response) {
          table.ajax.reload();

          if (response === true) {
            Swal.fire("\u0412\u0456\u0434\u0432\u0456\u0434\u0443\u0432\u0430\u043D\u043D\u044F \u0434\u043E\u0434\u0430\u043D\u043E");
          }
        });

      case 2:
        _ref4 = _context2.sent;
        desc = _ref4.value; //ПЕРВАЯ СТРОЧКА НА КОТОРОЮ РУГАЕТСЯ

      case 4:
      case "end":
        return _context2.stop();
    }
  }
}, _callee2);


 })));
```

Проблема именно со строчкой `desc = _ref4.value;`

Я не пойму, почему генерирует именно такой файл и как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Пометьте в коде где эти строчки, на которые он ругается? 1081, 152, особенно где это выражение: `desc = _ref4.value;`

Comment: @Leonid пометил

Comment: `_context2.sent` возвращает `undefined`, что это и откуда?

Comment: @Leonid На одну строку предыдущей... Тоже сгенерировано webpack'ом...